# Occluding parts of an object behind a transparent object

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to make some glass windows that are see-through but occlude everything behind them. The only thing that should be drawn behind these windows is a skybox.

My plan was to have a quad behind each window which would have a material with a masking shader applied to it.

I wrote this shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Mask"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "Queue" = "Geometry-1" }
        LOD 100

        Blend Zero One

        Pass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Which results in this effect, which comes pretty close!

[image]

The glass material is drawn, the occluder then stops rendering everything behind it, including the parts of the desk that are behind the occluder.

Also, as expected, when I move the occluder in front of the glass, the glass stops being rendered.

[image]

All I want to add to this effect is that my skybox should be drawn.

I tried messing around with the rendering queue, setting my skybox to draw just before the occluder shader (at Geometry - 2) but couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Any help as to how to achieve this effect would be wonderful.

Comment: If you place it behind, set `ZWRITE ON` and `ZTEST ALWAYS` it should overwrite what's in front and render the skybox only. But you can't put something in front of the occluder, unless you use an additional stencil mask (that you draw using `ZTEST LEQUAL`

Comment: What if you use ```BLEND ONE ZERO```?

Comment: I answered my own question, but thanks for the suggestions. I didn't get it to work with `ZWRITE ON` and `ZTEST ALWAYS`. `BLEND ONE ZERO` draws the quad in front of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a camera stack to draw the skybox instead.

1. I added a new camera as a child of my current one and marked it as an overlay camera.
2. I set the culling mask of my (old) main camera to 'Nothing', making it draw just the skybox.
3. I set the culling mask of my new camera to 'Everything', making it draw... everything.
4. I added the overlay camera to the camera stack of the first one.

My main camera then renders nothing but a skybox, after which the overlay camera draws everything else. When the camera then tries to render the mask material, nothing is drawn behind the quad for the overlay camera, like shown in my answer. Since the main camera already drew a skybox on that position, it is still visible.